# How cities with deceitful robots score higher in happiness?

Tags: society, humans, artificial-intelligence, robots

Set in the immediate future AI took many forms from an invisible alarm clock that wakes you only after you had done with wet dreams to an autonomous flying vehicle that map out routes filled with supermodels or those that have the potential but still be on time to your destination. However a recent survey revealed that people are more comfortable and more corporative with robots that is programmed to be deceitful, although the sampling size and the nature of the test is questionable but generally or rather statistically the trend ironically shows that people are more willing to trust a deceitful robot, so my question is how can such a city continue to prosper when other model remains stagnant?

Comment: [Lie] "I am a statistically representative human, and I will take your happiness survey."

Comment: [threat] "Happiness is mandatory. Are you happy?"

Comment: It's all in the nitty gritty detail, ie, *how* this deceitfulness functions.  Malicious deceit is not the same as the sort of deceptions we might call being polite or kind.

Answer (score 2):

**According to *some* surveys, almost everybody lies every day.**

"I hope I'm not bothering you." - "Of course not. Do come in."
"Daddy, can I have a cookie?" - "Sorry, no cookies left."
"Do you think this dress looks good?" - "Yes, dear."
"Nice to see you." - "Nice to see you, too."

AI that is *bluntly honest* might not do that. Take your example, the AI routing traffic so that the drivers can ogle supermodels. How do you think the *supermodels* feel about that? Or people in a nice, previously quiet, residential street with an above-average number of good-looking people?

Or consider Asimov's [three laws of robotics](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThreeLawsCompliant), which imply that a robot *must* disobey the human "master" if that is necessary to save the human. But how about discouraging unhealthy habits? Or those which harm other humans? A robot might decide that it must lie to humans to stop them from self-harm.

Comment: You missed the most important: "How are you?" "I'm fine, etc."

Comment: If you talk about three laws (un)safe, you should mention the reulting law 0 that lead to some robot uprisings: "A robot may not harm humanity, or through inaction allow humanity to come to harm." or in other terms: Disregard laws 1-3 to ensure survival of humanity. Killing one dificult human hardly matters in the grand scheme...